# LaTeX equivalent of \wd

Tags: boxes, lengths

Please consider the following code:

```
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{some text}
\newlength{\widthmybox}
\settowidth{\widthmybox}{\usebox{\mybox}}
```

Is `\widthmybox` then equivalent to `\wd\mybox`?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Underneath the hood, `\settowidth` is calling `\wd` to measure the width of the boxes content.

Comment: @PaulGessler Fair question.  They do appear to be equivalent when tested with `\rule{\widthmybox}{2pt}` and `\rule{\wd\mybox}{2pt}`.  But I'm getting errors when trying to replace the `\wd\mybox` with `\widthmybox` in a more complicated scenario.  So I wonder if their apparent equivalence is actually context dependent.

Comment: You can show the width using rules, as you tested, or by doing `\showthe\wd\mybox` and `\showthe\widthmybox` in the document and then inspecting the log file (both report `42.55563pt` in my minimal document for this case).

Comment: @PaulGessler Thanks for that information. Since the log results suggest they are numerically equivalent, I've either misapplied the commands (in my more complicated scenario) or they're not always interchangeable.  Hmm.

Comment: Do you want to create a minimal document that shows the problem and edit your question to hopefully find a fix for that use case, or what should we do with this question here?

Comment: @steven_nevets: Does your more complicated scenario involve assignment of box lengths within of a TeX group? In this case the box lengths might be different. And which errors do occur at all?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer In fact, the commands involve the length of a box containing the argument of a user-defined list.  But my efforts are so convoluted, I'm not prepared to share them. The error reports that my list is undefined.

Comment: @steven_nevets: How do you define the lists? With `etoolbox`?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No, the list is defined as a LaTeX environment. The commands test whether or not the argument is empty using `\ifthenelse{\widththmargbox=0}{}{(#1)}` and `\ifthenelse{\wd\thmargbox=0}{}{(#1)}`.  The latter works, but the former does not.

Comment: @steven_nevets: You should show us what you have, otherwise it's difficult to provide a solution

Comment: @PaulGessler After further analysis, I discovered that I misapplied the `\widththmargbox`.  It now works as a replacement for `\wd\thmargbox` as you'd expect. If you care to post your preceding comments (as to the equivalence of the commands) in the form of an answer, I'll select it officially.  Thanks for your help. And thank you, Christian, for your added consideration.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a coding error whose details weren't provided and which got fixed in the meantime.

Comment: My question may have been prompted by a coding error, but it stands on its own merit, and the accepted answer may prove helpful to other users.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The equivalent for `\wd` in LaTeX is `\wd`. `;-)` Well, it's not documented in the manual, but it surely can be used.

The “official” way would be

```
% in the preamble
\newsavebox{\mybox}
\newlength{\wdofmybox}

% at usage time
\sbox{\mybox}{some text}
\settowidth{\wdofmybox}{\usebox{\mybox}}
```

and then `\wdofmybox` can be used anywhere TeX expects a length.

A simpler

```
\setlength{\wdofmybox}{\wd\mybox}
```

has the same effect and is faster, because it doesn't require TeX to rebox the contents of `\mybox`. However you should remember that `\wd` is a primitive command that wants a `<number>` after it (which `\mybox` actually is) and ***no*** braces. In other words, `\wd{\mybox}` is illegal and will result in several errors.

You can even avoid the `\setlength` passage, using directly `\wd\mybox` where needed, but you can't say

```
\addtolength{\wd\mybox}{3pt}
```

and for something like this you need an auxiliary length register.

Comment: That is exactly the illumination I was hoping for; thank you very much.  May I ask, what in the command `\settowidth{\wdofmybox}{\usebox{\mybox}}` requires TeX to "rebox the contents of `\mybox`", as you suggest?

Comment: @steven_nevets `\usebox{\mybox}` delivers the already built box, just to be boxed again by `\sbox`

Answer (score 3):

### Equivalence analysis

They are *not* equivalent. `\settowidth` adds another boxing layer, from the LaTeX kernel (`latex.ltx`):

```
% #1: \ht, \dp or \wd
% #2: The argument of \settoheight, \settodepth, or \settowidth
% #3: The box contents
\def\@settodim#1#2#3{%
  \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{{#3}}%
  #2#1\@tempboxa
  \setbox\@tempboxa\box\voidb@x
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\settoheight{\@settodim\ht}
\DeclareRobustCommand\settodepth {\@settodim\dp}
\DeclareRobustCommand\settowidth {\@settodim\wd}
```

With the additional `setbox...\hbox` the token register of `\everyhbox` will be inserted at the start of the `\hbox`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{some text}
\newlength{\widthmybox}

\everyhbox{\kern100pt}

\settowidth{\widthmybox}{\usebox{\mybox}}
\typeout{* \string\wd\string\mybox=\the\wd\mybox}
\typeout{* \string\widthmybox=\the\widthmybox}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Result:

```
* \wd\mybox=42.55563pt
* \widthmybox=142.55563pt
```

In practice, the token register `\everyhbox` is usually empty, but it can contain stuff that contributes to the widths.

### Package settobox

If you want assign box dimensions to length registers, then take a look at package `settobox`. It wraps the "low level" stuff with `\wd` in LaTeX macros. With `\settoboxwidth` we get:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{settobox}

\newsavebox{\mybox}
\savebox{\mybox}{some text}
\newlength{\widthmybox}

\everyhbox{\kern100pt}

\settoboxwidth{\widthmybox}{\mybox}
\typeout{* \string\wd\string\mybox=\the\wd\mybox}
\typeout{* \string\widthmybox=\the\widthmybox}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Now the values are equal, because the additional boxing level is avoided:

```
* \wd\mybox=42.55563pt
* \widthmybox=42.55563pt
```